# Não consigo inserir dados no sqlite usando javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, sqlite, apache-cordova, jquery-mobile

Estou criando um app de smartphone usando Cordova para um projeto da faculdade. o App consiste de um cadastro simples de pacientes. Estou tendo dificuldades em gravar dados no banco.

Inicialmente a gravação estava funcionando, mas esqueci de incluir um campo de id com auto incremento na tabela, e a partir daí nada funcionou. O mais estranho é que a função de callback de sucesso é executada, ou seja, aparentemente não há erro no insert.

também tive o cuidado de testar cada comando em um editor de base de dados sqlite e todos funcionaram corretamente.

O Código Javascript que estou usando está abaixo:

```
// Criando/abrindo o banco
var db = openDatabase("graudecoma", "1.0", "base de dados da aplicacao", 200000);

// criando a tabela caso ela não exista
    db.transaction(function(transaction){
        transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pacientes ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "nome" TEXT NOT NULL, "abertura_ocular" INTEGER NOT NULL, "resposta_motora" INTEGER NOT NULL, "resposta_verbal" INTEGER NOT NULL, "diagnostico" TEXT)', [], null, db.onError);
    })

// função callback de erro
db.onError = function(transaction, e) {
  alert("Aconteceu um erro: " + e.message);
  console.log(e.message);
}

// função de callback de sucesso de insert
db.onSuccess = function(transaction, e) {
  alert("Dados Gravados com Sucesso!");
  console.log(e);
}

// função temporaria que lista resultados
db.getResults = function (transaction, r) {
    console.log('deu certo!');
    console.log(r);

   for(var i = 0; i < r.rows.length; i++){
       console.log(r.rows.item(i)[['id']]);
       console.log(r.rows.item(i)[['nome']]);
       console.log(r.rows.item(i)[['diagnostico']]);
   }
}

// aqui vai o insert
db.transaction(function(transaction){
  transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO pacientes(nome, abertura_ocular, resposta_motora, resposta_verbal, diagnostico) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [$('#nome').val(), $('input[name="sintoma-1"]:checked').val(), $('input[name="sintoma-2"]:checked').val(), $('input[name="sintoma-3"]:checked').val(), $('#diagnostico').val()], db.onSuccess, db.onError);
})

// consulta no banco
db.transaction(function(transaction){
    transaction.executeSql("SELECT * FROM pacientes", [], db.getResults, db.onError);
})
```

Como disse inicialmente, estava funcionando, mas após eu alterar o `CREATE TABLE` para incluir o id eu não consegui mais gravar.

Obs: eu também tive o cuidado de recriar a tabela. também experimentei criar um novo banco **graudecoma2** e também uma nova tabela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu problema é mais simples do que você pensa, remova o `AUTOINCREMENT`, pois toda chave primaria será por padrão `AUTOINCREMENT`

Abaixo tem um link com dúvidas frequentes sobre o SQLLite, só que em ingles, pode ser que te ajude futuramente [SqlLite](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1)

Comment: Puxa, era isso mesmo! valeu mesmo!

Comment: @MarcusVBP caso a resposta atenda a sua pergunta, marque-a como resolvida para auxiliar que outras pessoas com dúvidas similares possam visualizar melhor a resolução.